# Qt. Как сериализовать объекты содержащие коллекции?

Tags: c++, qt, сериализация

Имеются вот такие вот классы:

```
class Institution //Класс "учебное заведение"
{
    ...
private:
    ...
    QList<Pupil *> Pupils; //Коллекция учеников
};

class Pupil //Класс "ученик"
{
    ...
private:
    ...
    QList<Exam *> Lessons; //Коллекция предметов
};

class Exam //Класс "экзамен"
{
    ...
};
```

Необходимо сериализовать коллекцию объектов класса Institution (хотя я не уверен уместно ли называть это сериализацией), а именно сохранить это коллекцию в бинарник и потом "взять" её оттуда.

Сохранение (здесь проблем нет, т.е. sizeof работает как надо):

```
QList<Institution *> institutions;
...
Institution bf("", 0);
char str[1024];
strcpy(str, filename.toStdString().c_str());
std::ofstream out(str, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
for (int i = 0; i < institutions.size(); i++)
{
    bf = *institutions[i];
    int a = sizeof bf;
    out.write((char *) &bf, sizeof bf);
}
out.close();
```

Считывание (здесь, понятное дело, sizeof не работает, т.к. размер вложенных коллекций заранее не определить):

```
QList<Institution *> institutions;
...
institutions.clear();
char str[1024];
strcpy(str, filename.toStdString().c_str());
std::ifstream in(str, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
while (!in.eof() && in.peek() != EOF)
{
    Institution *bf = new Institution("", 0);
    int a = sizeof bf;
    in.read((char *) bf, sizeof *bf); //!
    institutions.append(bf);
}
in.close();
```

Теперь и вопрос, как всё-таки можно записать и считать эту коллекцию в/из бинарника, не изменяя структуру классов(!)?

Или может быть есть что-то подобное как в Java?

```
/*Коллекция*/
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
/*Запись*/
try
{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.toString());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(list);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
}

/*Считывание*/
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.toString());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
try
{
    list = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
}
ois.close();
fis.close();
```

**UPD#1:**
Всё решилось использованием `QDataStream`, заменой всех *коллекций с указателями на объекты классов* на *коллекции с объектами классов* и перегрузкой `operator <<`, `operator >>` для `QDataStream`:

```
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Institution &s);
QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Institution &s);
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Pupil &s);
QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Pupil &s);
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Exam &s);
QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Exam &s);
```

Пример реализации:

```
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Institution &s)
{
    out << s.getName() << s.getID() << s.getPupils();
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Institution &s)
{
    QString Name;
    int ID;
    QList<Pupil> Pupils;
    in >> Name >> ID >> Pupils;
    s = Institution(Name, ID, Pupils);
    return in;
}
```

Comment: @kff, с `QDataStream` возникает та же проблема - не известен размер считываемого вложенного списка, либо я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: @kff, прошу прощения, пошел переопределять ввод/вывод в поток.

Comment: @НиколайШепелев Что вы имеете в виду под "sizeof работает как надо", то есть что вы получаете этим оператором?

Comment: @Cerbo, я имел в виду (тогда ещё думал, что он работает как мне надо), что он корректно определял размер объекта со вложенным контейнером, а как оказалось нет. Ибо у меня там (во вложенном контейнере) указатели на объекты, а не сами объекты. Был бы просто контейнер объектов, то `sizeof` определил бы корректно размер объекта (при записи). Но считать бы всё-равно не удалось без костылей, так как в бинарник не сохранялся бы размер вложенного контейнера.

Comment: Если вы нашли решение проблемы пожалуйста опубликуйте его как ответ, а из вопроса его лучше убрать.

Answer (score 3):

Всё решилось использованием `QDataStream`, заменой всех коллекций с указателями на объекты классов на коллекции с объектами классов и перегрузкой `operator <<`, `operator >>` для `QDataStream`:

```
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Institution &s);
QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Institution &s);
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Pupil &s);
QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Pupil &s);
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Exam &s);
QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Exam &s);
```

Пример реализации:

```
QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &out, const Institution &s)
{
    out << s.getName() << s.getID() << s.getPupils();
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &in, Institution &s)
{
    QString Name;
    int ID;
    QList<Pupil> Pupils;
    in >> Name >> ID >> Pupils;
    s = Institution(Name, ID, Pupils);
    return in;
}
```